# JSON to HTML5 table

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, json, html

How to populate a HTML5 table if you receive data in JSON format in jQuery Ajax and based on a specific column on a row color that row on a table (Using bootstrap 4 CSS styles?)

For example if i receive a dataset in JSON format like this:

```
{ "name":"John", "age":31, "city":"New York" };
```

The column city is New York so the table row should be colored green so the finished product should be like this:

```
<tr class="success">
  <td>John</td>
  <td>31</td>
  <td>New York</td>
</tr>
```

I'm fairly new at jQuery can anyone guide me through how this can be achieved?

I'm using datatables library at the moment and what i have done is this:

```
function btnSearch_Click() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "index.aspx/GetJobs",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      $('.table-sortable').dataTable({
        destroy: true,
        data: data,
        columns: [
        {
          'd': 'Name'
        },
        {
          'd': 'Age'
        },
        {
          'd': 'City'
        }]
      });
    }
  });
};
```

Current HTML5 code is displayed bellow

```
<table class="table table-hover thead-inverse  table-bordered table-sortable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>City</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

But when I click the button no data rows are returned by the browser (SQL Server does return data). Also as i mentioned i do not know how to accomplish that if specific data is returned in a row i need to color it...

Thank you for your help in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$('.table-sortable').dataTable({
  destroy: true,
  data: data,
  columns: [
    { "data": "name" },
    { "data": "age" },
    { "data": "city" },
  ]
});
```

Comment: I already tried it does not work. Also it does not answer my question how to color the data based on the column data string that is returned for example if new York  <tr class="success"> if Las Vegas <tr class="danger"> and so on. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

For using `DataTables` with `ajax` you usually have something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.table-sortable').dataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": "index.aspx/GetJobs",
            "type": "POST"
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "age" },
            { "data": "city" },
        ]
    });
});
```

As you can see the plugin itself has the functionality to use `ajax`.

So by default your returned data from server should contain a property `data` which contains the elements that are about to be rendered. You can actually specifiy this by using the `dataSrc` ([reference](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc)) prop of `ajax`, you can set it to other name or remove it if you use plain collection:

```
"ajax": {
            "url": "index.aspx/GetJobs",
            "type": "POST"
            "dataSrc": ""
},
```

This however does not change the `data` name in `columns` declaration so don't change it there.

You can read more about accepted formats and see examples in the [official documentation](https://datatables.net/).

Now regarding your question about row styling, there are a lot of callbacks and declarations which you can use to achieve that. I personally prefer using the `createdRow` callback ([reference](https://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow)):

```
"createdRow": function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
   if ( parseInt(data[1]) >= 18 ) {
     $(row).addClass( 'success' );
   }
}
```

So in this case if the age (second column based on 0-start-indexing) of the current row is above 18 it will add the desired class.

---

I hope this helps resolving your issues, if there still are problems you can try making a working jsfiddle so we can try debugging it in a "real-like" situation.

Comment: No everything is fine managed to figure out this one by myself. Your idea works. Also the coloring feature also works. Everything is fine thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is just to get an idea, i will add button click code

```
$("button").click(function(){
    var obj = JSON.parse('[{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"},{ "name":"John1", "age":30, "city":"New York"}]');
    var t = $('#example');

    for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++)   // iterate data from json
    { 
    var name = obj[i].name;
    var age = obj[i].age;
    var classStyle = 'yellow'
    if(name=='John')
    {
        classStyle = 'green';
    }
        $('#example').append('<tr style=background:'+classStyle+'><td>'+name+'</td><td>'+age+'</td></tr>');

    }

});
```